# How to get data from database (JDBC) in Soap UI

Tags: soapui, soap-client

I would like to get data from request to database (JDBC) in SOAP UI. For example i have such connection and request : 
[image]

In other step I try to get data from database:

```
 def get_iccid =    context.expand('${DB_Get_Free_SIM#ResponseAsXml#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/ICC_ID[1]}');
log.info("iccid from database  = " + get_iccid);
```

and I didn't get anything.

Comment: Do you have to do anything with the retrieved data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `XPath`, try adding the wildcard to match any namespace:

```
//*:Results[1]/*:ResultSet[1]/*:Row[1]/*:ICC_ID[1]
```

In your code:

```
def get_iccid = 
context.expand('${DB_Get_Free_SIM#ResponseAsXml#//*:Results[1]/*:ResultSet[1]/*:Row[1]/*:ICC_ID[1]}');
```

Note that if there is only one `<Results>`,`<ResultsSet>`,`<Row>` element it's not necessary to specify `[1]`, so if your *JDBC* response is something like:

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="10">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
           <ICC_ID>someValue</ICC_ID>
        </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

You can simplify your `XPath` as:

```
//*:Results/*:ResultSet/*:Row/*:ICC_ID
```

As @Siking note in the comments, *JDBC TestStep* response has always the same structure until `<Row>` so it's safe to start with `//*:Row`, then the `XPath` could be more simple:

```
//*:Row/*:ICC_ID
```

Comment: For SoapUI JDBC replies it should _always_ be safe to start your XPath with `//*:Row`. The `//*:Results/*:ResultSet` can be dropped.

Comment: @siking right good point! because the xml structure until `<Row>` are always the same.